# Ftp user can't login when restricted to sub-directory like .../httpdocs/foo

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

I'm creating a new ftp user on Plesk (CentOS) trough shell using:

```
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/domain.com user1
```

This works. No problems here.

I then then add another user but this time restricted to /httpdocs/foo not just (domain.com)

```
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo user2
```

Now I get an incorrect login error:

```
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.3c Server (ProFTPD) [x.x.x.x]
Command:    USER user2
Response:   331 Password required for user2
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
```

My `bin/passwd` file has the user2 there and I tried to change it there and I get the exat same thing

`user2:x:10038:505::/var/www/vhosts/domain.com:/bin/false`  **//Logs In**
`user2:x:10038:505::/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo:/bin/false`  **//Fails**

I restart the service using: `/etc/init.d/xinetd restart`

Any ideas?
Thanks

**Solution:**

```
/usr/sbin/useradd -g psacln -d /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo user2

chown -R user2:psacln /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo

chmod 775 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo

passwd user2
```

Comment: Could you describe why it's necessary to add FTP user directly in system, but not in Plesk? Did you understand that this user can't be  backuped / migrated or necessary changes will be not applied in case of plesk upgrade?

Comment: I'm automating the process of adding new customers with  a "one-click app". It also installs a wordpress, created db for it and installs it.Is there a way to automate trought Plesk only?

Comment: Yes, of course. Plesk API and CLI allows to create domains, additional FTP accounts, databases and database users. Here the API reference http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/64508.htm, here is CLI reference http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-unix-cli/63094.htm

Comment: The main issue in your current approach that plesk don't aware about all customization and can broke it. Second point is that you have to handle all your customization by yourself every time, if you can do that why you need plesk?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does user2 have access to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo`?  Try using `chown` to set that user as the owner, see if that works.  ProFTPd could be failing the login due to the destination directory being inaccessible to that user.

Comment: Not only that directory, but user2 must have **at least** +x permission to all directories beneath its home.  To test, as root in the shell, `su user2`. Then `cd /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/foo` If you get permission denied, remove a folder from the end of the list until you find one that works. (ie, try `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs` next, then `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com`, etc.). Add the +x permission for user2 to the folder that didn't work after one that did, then retry from the top.  If your fs supports acls, this is as simple as `setfacl -m u:user2:x <directory>`.

Comment: Yes. You are both right. I did chown and reclusive chmod on the folder and it works great. Added the solution that worked in question. Thank you!